# OsmDroid: TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)

Tags: android, osmdroid

I got OsmDroid log like this:

> OsmDroid: TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null
> (map shutdown?)
>
> OsmDroid: Tile cache increased from 9 to 24

What is the reason I am getting OsmDroid's log like this [image]

**How to fix it?**

[image]

```
  // open street map
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.11'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: no did not find any solution, still i am getting this log message

Comment: can you describe the scenario? When do you see these logs and what's the library's behaviour?

Comment: This post may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062562/osmdroid-change-tiles-cache-in-storage

Answer (score 1):

Let's check this out
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/FAQ

Coz it helped me when I had the same issue.

--

1. send user agent

```
Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(context.getPackageName());
```

2. use zoom level < 20 by default.
3. add `network_security_config.xml` into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

````
<network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">openptmap.org</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>```
````

Comment: i tried this ans, still i am getting same error